# Magento Nginx 502 Gateway Error

Tags: magento, nginx

After updating Magento with Patch 6788 and update the Intenso Theme I am getting the following error on some of the product URLs:

```
2015/11/14 16:55:12 [notice] 1594#0: signal process started
2015/11/14 16:56:10 [error] 1602#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 69.204.XXX.XXX, server: localhost, request: "GET /houseware/karu-non-stick-bowl-w-g-16cm.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:7161", host: "107.170.XXX.XXX", referrer: "http://107.170.XXX.XXX/houseware.html"
```

Basically I am getting a 502 on some of the product pages.
does anyone knows how to resolve this.

I have NGINX server + PHP_FPM + MYSQL setup.

Comment: Found the solution Intenso just updated they latest theme with patch and they resolved the issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Incidentally, this question would probably be *on topic* at the [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com)